# Show that: $ X \ {\text{is}}\ \mu{\text{-integrable}} \implies \sum_{k=1}^\infty\mu(\{\mid X\mid ≥ k\}) < \infty$

Tags: statistics, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Assignment:

> Let $(\Omega,\mathfrak{A},\mu)$ be a measure space and $X: \Omega \rightarrow \bar{\mathbb{R}}$ a $\mathfrak{A}$-$\bar{\mathfrak{B}}$-measurable function.

Show that: $$ X \ {\text{is}}\ \mu{\text{-integrable}} \implies \sum_{k=1}^\infty\mu(\{\mid X\mid ≥ k\}) < \infty$$

My thoughts:
Since $X$ is $\mu$-integrable we have $\int_{\Omega}Xd\mu <\infty$. Firstly I define $$M_k:=\{\omega\in\Omega: \mid X(\omega)\mid ≥k\})$$

Thus we also have $M_k \subset M_{k+1}$
I assume that $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\mu(\{\mid X\mid ≥ k\}) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mu(M_k)= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\int\chi_{M_k}d\mu = \int\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\chi_{M_k}d\mu  = {\infty}$$

However $$\int\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\chi_{M_k}d\mu  = {\infty}\iff M:=\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty}M_k \neq \emptyset $$
Since, if I suppose that $M = \emptyset$, I can find for arbitrary $\omega\in\Omega$ some $k_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $k≥k_0: \chi_{M_k}(\omega)=0$ so that

$$\int\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\chi_{M_k}d\mu = \int\sum_{k=1}^{k_0}\chi_{M_k} + \sum_{k=k_0}^\infty\chi_{M_k} d\mu < \infty$$

And that is all I've got so far. Does this approach work? Or is there a better way to solve the problem? Because I'm struggling to find a contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Integrate the pointwise inequality $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\mathbf 1_{\{\mid X\mid \geqslant k\}}=\lfloor |X|\rfloor\leqslant |X|.$$

Comment: I hope, I should not literally integrate the inequality. However, I'm wondering how to establish your inequality. What do I know about the value of $X(\omega)$ for arbitrary $\omega$? Since $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\mathbb{1}_{\{\mid X\mid≥k\}}$ is basically the amount of sets $M_k$ with $\omega \in M_k$ how is that related to the actual value on $X$?

Comment: Yes you should "literally" integrate the inequality. To establish it, use the integer part formulation (in other words, what is the problem, the $=$ part or the $\leqslant$ part?).

Comment: Yes, of course. I solved it, thanks for your help.